# Spivak Calculus, Ch 11, Problem 11a): Proof that if $f$ weakly convex, then [$f$ convex $\iff$ graph of $f$ contains no straight line segments].

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

> 11. Call a function $f$ *weakly convex* on an interval if for $a<b<c$ in this interval we have
>
> $$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \leq \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
>
> (a) Show that a weakly convex function is convex if and only if its
> graph contains no straight line segments. (Sometimes a weakly convex
> function is simply called "convex", while convex functions in our
> sense are called "strictly convex").

The proof I came up with differs from the solution manual, and I would like to verify if it is correct.

**Proof**

By assumption, $f$ is weakly convex.

Assume $f$ is also (strictly) convex.

Assume the graph of $f$ contains a straight line segment.

Let $a<b<c$ be points on the line segment portion of $f$'s graph. Then,

$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}$$

But this contradicts our assumption that $f$ is strictly convex, which implies that

$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}<\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}$$

Therefore, $f$ convex $\implies$ graph of $f$ contains no straight line segments.

Now assume, for proof by contradiction, that the graph of $f$ contains no straight line segments.

For any $a<b<c$, we know that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \leq \frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}$

Assume that for some $a,b,$ and $c$ such that $a<b<c$ we have $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}=\alpha$.

Let $x_2 \in (b,c)$. Then by weak convexity

$$\frac{f(x_2)-f(b)}{x_2-b}\leq \alpha\tag{1}$$

Let $x_1 \in (a,b)$.

Assume for proof by contradiction that

$$\frac{f(x_1)-f(a)}{x_1-a}<\alpha\tag{2}$$

Then, $\alpha<\frac{f(b)-f(x_1)}{b-x_1} \leq \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1} \leq \frac{f(x_2)-f(b)}{x_2-b}$.

But this contradicts $(1)$.

Therefore, by proof by contradiction,

$$\forall x, x \in (a,b) \implies \frac{f(x_1)-f(a)}{x_1-a}=\alpha$$

But then the graph of $f$ contains a straight line segment between $a$ and $b$, which contradicts our initial assumption of no straight lines in the graph of $f$.

Therefore, by proof by contradiction, $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}<\frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a}$$

That is, $f$ is convex.

Therefore, graph of $f$ contains no straight line segments $\implies f$ convex.